# What is this oval device on this car's doors?

Tags: part-identification

What is this oval-shaped device on this car’s doors? I haven’t seen it before.

[image: Car zoomed out]

[image: Device close up]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner has likely added them to stop the paint getting damaged when opening the car doors against a wall.  The plastic piece will hit the wall first protecting the door.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the purpose? The door handle seems to protrude farther than this, so won't the door handle hit the wall instead?

Comment: Okay, it seems you are right. My doubts about the effectiveness of this product aside, I was able to find it: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33020869413.html

Comment: @hb20007 The door handle might stick out further when the door is *closed* but when you open it the door pivots at the hinge and the edge is what leads and that means the protective attachment gets there before the handle.

Comment: @hb20007 because it's most relevant when the door is opened, thin plastic strip slipped over the edge of the door can be quite effective.  A major reason to use them is if you park 2 cars next to each other on a drive or in tight car parks, to avoid damaging the other car as much as this one - the edge of a door can leave a little dent quite easily.